# Why do I get different results in perl from the s, y, and tr operators?

Tags: perl, tr, string-substitution

`perl -pe 's/A/ā/' <<< "avatAr"` gives me `avatār` as expected.

But both `perl -pe 'y/A/ā/' <<< "avatAr"` and `perl -pe 'tr/A/ā/' <<< "avatAr"` give me `avat�r`.

Why is this so? And how might I get the same results as the substitution?

I also tried `perl -Mutf8 -C24 -pe 'tr/A/ā/' <<< "avatAr"` and it gave me

```
Wide character in print at -e line 1, <> line 1.
avatār
```

What am I doing wrong to get this warning? Identical results for `y` instead of `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to needing `-Mutf8` as kaavannan has explained, you are getting the 'wide character' warning because the numbers in `-C24` are numbers, not flags, so that should have been written as `-C6`. Even better would be to use a flag and enable stderr too: `-CS`.